# MVC 5 Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datetimepicker'

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building an MVC 5 application and i am trying to use [Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS/).

I have a Javascript file with

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });
});
```

This is how my bundle looks like

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                  "~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/moment.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        // Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
        // visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

This is the view

```
    <h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CreateEditSeasonViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })                 

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker", placeholder = "Enter start date here..." } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker", placeholder = "Enter end date here..." } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

  <div>
      @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>
```

When i run the app i am getting this error in IE 11 and Firefox.
[image: IE 11 runtime error]

What am i doing wrong, and how i can get rid of this roadblock?

**Update:** I have followed a number of blogs, including these;

[adding-datetimepicker-control-to-mvc-project](http://blog.jigsawpieces.me/2014/07/23/lbd-adding-datetimepicker-control-to-mvc-project/)

[bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: Is your datetimepicker file named `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`? Check your script folder then check your bundle includes.

Comment: @Jasen datetimepicker is part of the js function in that group (bootstrap bundle). I named the file DatePickerReady

Comment: So you renamed `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` to `DatePickerReady.js`? Do you have any 404s when loading page resources?

Comment: @Jasen No i didn't rename anything, see my bundle file. I placed the custom code in DatePickerReady, everything also is as is from Nuget

Comment: According to the [datetimepicker library](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/src/js) the script name is `bootstrap-date` _`time`_ `picker.js` your bundle has `~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js`.

Comment: @Jasen i am going by http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you plugin isn't getting loaded, or isn't getting loaded in time. Some things to check:

- Have you rebuilt your project?
- Have you used firebug or other developer tools to ensure that the datepicker javascript is being loaded?
- Are you placing the bootstrap and jquery bundles in the correct order?
- Are you loading them before you make your call to datetimepicker()?

Comment: jQuery runs before bootstrap and then my custom file. I have even tried to place the bundles at the top of the layout page as supposed to the default settings at the bottom. Nothing is working still, i am getting the same error. I know that `DatePickerReady.js` is running since method `datetimepicker` is showing in the error

Comment: @Komengem The fact that datetimepicker is showing up in your error message only proves that you are calling datetimepicker(), it doesn't indicate that it is loading correctly- in fact it's likely just the opposite.